# Bayes estimators intuition: why can't we simply maximize the posterior?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I'm learning about Bayes estimator, and I'm still confused about why we can't simply use the posterior for this purpose. More specifically, suppose I need to estimate a parameter $\theta$, which I assume to be random and follow a prior distribution $\pi(\theta)$. Now I observe some data $X$ and I can use the Bayes rule to update my prior distribution to get my posterior:
$$\pi(\theta|X) = \frac{f(X|\theta) \pi(\theta)}{f(X)}$$
Then it seems natural to me to define the Bayes estimator to be simply the argmax of $\pi(\theta|X)$. However, in the formal definition, the Bayes estimator is defined to be the minimizer of the Bayes' risk. Can someone explain to me the intuition behind this? And what are the advantages of defining it this way ?

Comment: Afaik, the bayes' estimator minimises the expected value of the posterior only. Perhaps add the source of the definition?

Comment: Hi @whoisit, the formal definition I was referring to is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator . In the definition part they mention the Bayes' risk.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you get to pick the loss function in the definition of the Bayes estimator, and I think you'll get your argmax definition when the loss function is something like "the penalty for any loss is infinite." (Not sure if that can be made rigorous or is just a heuristic, depends on what is allowed for a loss function.)

Anyway, here's an example where the argmax gives an unintuitive answer.

Say that the prior on theta is that it's equal to $-1$ with probability $.001$, and the rest of its $.999$ probability is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. The variable $X$ depends on $\theta$ as follows. If $\theta = -1$, then $X$ is $17$ with probability $.001$ and is otherwise drawn uniformly from $[0, 1]$. If $\theta$ is between $0$ and $1$, then $X$ is drawn uniformly from $[0, 1]$.

Now for any $X$ whatsoever, the argmax you have defined will be $-1$, since any other $\theta$ has infinitesimal probability. But unless $X = 17$, in fact this is not a reasonable estimator for $\theta$ -- our belief that $\theta$ is $-1$ is very small and should go down when we see data other than $17$.

Comment: +1 I think that with a fully discrete posterior and a constant loss function for any failure to get the correct value precisely, then you can justify argmax.  But with a continuous posterior then you cannot, since the probability of being correct is $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but what if $\pi(\theta)$ and $f(X)$ are both densities and not probability ? Then they can clearly take a positive value for a specific $X$ or $\theta$. Or am I just confused about the correct application of Bayes rule ? Namely one cannot write it like that for densities.